# App starting as Single view and proceed to tabbar application

Tags: ios, tabbed

I am about to create an xcode iphone app which will lauch initially as a single view ( something like login and settings screens ) and then proceed to a tabbed bar application with multiple tabs .

how to do this -

should i create two differnet projects one single view and one tabbed application ?

and is it possible to roll two projects into one single app ?

or is there just another easier way. I have xcode 4.3 and planning to use storyboard insteaod of XIBs

rgds,

sumit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not start with two projects, as you'll have an incredibly difficult time integrating them into one app. This is pretty simple, but you do need to learn the basics of view controllers.

Use Storyboards, and start with a single view app, maybe inside a navigation controller.  Then do a transition to a tabbed view controller.

Upgrade to Xcode 4.6.3 or 5. Look at Apple's template apps for a tabbed application and a single view app to see how the storyboards look.  Then copy the storyboards in one to the other, and link them up.  This is definitely possible and straightforward, but you do need to understand how each view controller works with the others.

Comment: thanks, must i upgrade to xcode 4.6.3 ? i already have the option of single view and tabbed application projects ?

Comment: I don't think you have Storyboards in 4.3.  Using a later Xcode, not only resolves some bugs, but it will also allow you to access new features of the OS.  For example, you won't be able to develop for iOS7 without Xcode 5.

Comment: actually it has.. it is showing the mainstoryboard on creating new project. also i quoted the wrong version its not 4.3 its 4.2 actually

Comment: 4.2 is 5 major releases old.  The release notes below document that Xcode 4.5 is where they added support for view controller containment.  You may want that.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW3

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same situation once. I made a project as single view based app. without storyboard (since I was required to build compatible apps with iOS 4.3).

1. Made login screen as main view controller.
2. On login, I presented tab viewcontroller **modally**.
3. On sign out, I dismiss tab controller and return back to login screen.

If you have any queries, just ask it :)

Comment: Hi can u send me one small sample of these as m facing memory issue with the same kind of project..I am using navigation controller for the first two class then tabbar for next.back and forth...Every thing is working ok but memory is not releasing after i launch tabbar or coming back to navigation.